# uWSGI keepalive

Tags: python, nginx, uwsgi

Is it possible somehow to pass through the keepalive limitation of uwsgi? If not, what is the best way of persistent connection implementation. I'm using NGiNX + uWSGI (Python), and I want clients to have asynchronous updates from server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UWSGI supports keep-alive via --http-keepalive option if you receive requests via http.

```
/tmp$ cat app.py
def application(env, start_response):
    content = b"Hello World"
    start_response('200 OK', [
        ('Content-Type','text/html'),
        ('Content-Length', str(len(content))),
    ])
    return [content]
```

Run with:

```
/tmp$ uwsgi --http=:8000 --http-keepalive -w app &> /dev/null
```

And we can see `connect` calls via strace:

```
~$ strace -econnect wrk -d 10 -t 1 -c 1 http://127.0.0.1:8000 
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(8000), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
Running 10s test @ http://127.0.0.1:8000
  1 threads and 1 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    92.32us   56.14us   2.81ms   97.20%
    Req/Sec    11.10k   389.34    11.84k    68.32%
  111505 requests in 10.10s, 7.98MB read
Requests/sec:  11040.50
Transfer/sec:    808.63KB
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

See? Only one connection.

Comment: `-c 1` option sets how much connections active simultaneously, but it's not necessary works in keep-alive mode: https://github.com/wg/wrk/blob/91655b5520b524fc0b802ad12220c9dcd546757e/src/http_parser.c#L2123. UWSGI adds `Connection: close` to every response. But this `uwsgi` tool could work in keep-alive by workaround if size of content is known: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/HTTP.html?highlight=keep-alive#http-keep-alive. Anyway, your application gets a lot of separate requests.

Comment: @DenisKolodin

> but it's not necessary works in keep-alive mode `wrk` uses http/1.1 so keep-alive is a default mode. The same test with strace and `ab` shows `connect` on every request.

> But this uwsgi tool could work in keep-alive by workaround if size of content is known

It is not a workaround. It's a documented behavior) Most wsgi frameworks set correct Content-Length.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about two different things. If you want persistent connections from your clients to your app, you may want to use async modes (via ugreen, gevent...). In that way you will be able to maintain thousand of concurrent connections. Keepalive is a way to route multiple requests to the same connections, but this is pretty useless for your purpose. Instead If you are referring to persistent connections between nginx and uWSGI, there is no way (currently) in nginx to reach such behaviour. You may want to follow this ticket:

http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/ticket/66

it is about the fastrouter, but will be applied in httprouter too. But it is still under heavy development.